# How can I execute a specific chunk of code when my application crashes?

Tags: c#

Is there a way that I can execute a specific chunk of code when my application crashes? (i.e. If my application crashes, I would like to safely close some streams)

Comment: Your stream should already have a critical finalizer which runs on appdomain unload.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.

Comment: You may also want to check out Application.ThreadException.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx 

The above link has a nice example and explanation on the difference between AppDomain.UnhandledException and Application.ThreadException.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You should do it in a try-catch-finally block then.

Final block is what happens last when you catch an exception.
[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Techically if the app has crashed, the finally method won't be firing. (unless the crash occured during execution of finally). My guess is that the OP is talking about crashes occuring outside of bad coding practice, that is, crashes that are occuring through other means than failure to catch exceptions correctly.

Comment: can he put a try-catch block over the whole app? in a block that initializes GUI?